# Push Notifications Suddenly Stopped Working Using expo go after creating native android build

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

im using an expo managed workflow with latest expo and eas versions.The problem is that i wanted to integrate google ads so installed react-native-google-mobile-ads which required a native build so i ran expo prebuild and then npx run:android that created a development build .the problem is that now notifications are not working and i get this errior

```
[Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method getDevicePushTokenAsync on module ExpoPushTokenManager: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.muhammad1700.social_assistance. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.]
```

i have tried many solutions but nothing worked. I hope someone can help resolve this issue as deadline is upon me

Answer (score 1):

you need to set up Firebase Cloud Messaging to receive notifications on Android. As the [expo-notifications docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#configuration) says:

> Firebase Cloud Messaging credentials are required for all Android apps to receive push notifications in your app (except when testing in Expo Go). For more information, see how to get FCM credentials for your app.

So just follow the documentation, set FCM up and everything gonna work!